# iPhone card like flipping animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, flip

I'm trying to create a card flipping animation on iOS, and I'm failing miserably.
Basically I have a global View with a Controller. Inside I have a holderView, which contains the card.
I have the front of the card, which is the mainView, and then the back of the card, which is a flipSideView.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0
                            options:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
                         animations:^{
        NSLog(@"started");

        [mainView removeFromSuperview];
        [holderView addSubview:flipsideView];


    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        NSLog(@"completed");
    }];
```

That doesn't work, does weird things, I have tried a lot of different things but cannot get it to work perfectly.
Would anyone have an idea how I can do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:mainView
  toView:holderView
  duration:1.0f
  options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

That should work. Hope that Helps!

Comment: It works, awesome! Thanks!.
One small change in your code I had to make, was change holderView to flipsideView (that is the view when the card is flipped)