# flip uiview like ope a card with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, flip

I am developing an app in which I have to open a card like this video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srnRuhFvYl0&feature=youtu.be

Can some one suggest me any library or any way by which I can make this type of animation between 2 uiviews

Comment: See also [iPhone card like flipping animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984804/iphone-card-like-flipping-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their are many posts available for this question

[turn-a-page-like-a-book-with-uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477078/turn-a-page-like-a-book-with-uiview)

[3d-door-open-animation-between-two-uiviewcontrollers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685547/3d-door-open-animation-between-two-uiviewcontrollers)

[implementing-ibooks-page-curling THIS IS GREAT](http://wdnuon.blogspot.in/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html)

Hope you will find the solution from this .....

Answer (score 1):

try this demo for your effects.

[MPFlipViewController](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFlipViewController)

Comment: Hello Samir, i like this library... but can we flip entire page instead of fliping half?

Answer (score 0):

here you can implement logic with bellow animation..

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:yourView2 cache:YES];// Here i set UIView2
[yourView1 removeFromSuperview];// And here i remove UIView1
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here also you can use `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown` instead of `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`

Also see this Demo.. [leaves-developers](https://github.com/ole/leaves/tree/twopages)

Comment: [`+[UIView beginAnimations:context:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW14) `Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.`

Comment: @Shivam S.Kara you used this code?? and try demo??

Comment: Nope - I was just letting you know that the use of the non block-based api is discourages.

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
- (IBAction)viewCommentBtnClk:(id)sender
{
ShowCommentViewController *showCommentVC = [[ShowCommentViewController alloc]init];
showCommentVC.buss_id = business_id;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:showCommentVC animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self presentModalViewController:showCommentVC animated:YES];
[showCommentVC release];
}
```

Hope i helped.